# How to convert an array of type String to an array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string containing an array, and want to extract the array and play with its objects.

```
var arrayString = "[{'name': 'Ruwaida Abdo'}, {'name': 'Najlaa Saadi'}]";
```

Basically, I am dealing with a JSON file in which some properties are in fact arrays but stored as strings. Hence, I need to deal with them as strings and convert them to array to use their objects.

Comment: use `JSON.parse(arrayString)`. Read [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Also don't forget to surround it with try-catch block (in case malformed json string)

Comment: Please store them as a valid JSON string. It should have double quotes around keys and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a JSON string. You can [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it to get the object / array:

```
var array = JSON.parse(arrayString)
```

Edit: I see your JSON string has single quotes. You need to replace all of them with double quotes before parsing:

```
JSON.parse(arrayString.replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string. It has single quotes around the keys and values

Comment: @adiga totally missed that. Updated the answer, Thanks